# move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move file in PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that has worked just fine until recent PHP updates (Arch Linux). And I can’t seem to figure out how to resolve the issue. Here is the relevant portion of the script.

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
 ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");
 require_once "Mail.php";
 require_once "crypto_new.php";
 $target_path  = "./";
 $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
//stuff
}
```

It seems to bork up when trying to execute `move_uploaded_file`, and it throws the following error.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uploadedfile in /srv/http/test/receiver.php on line 14
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phppRkyQy' to './0a68457237fcc579c2ec03d69519f021' in /srv/http/test/receiver.php on line 14
```

Any idea what might be wrong and how to resolve it?

Comment: 1) you fail to check if an upload was actually performed. 2) you fail to check if the upload succeeded. 3) You blindly stumble onwards with a file which possibly doesn't exist. so... there's an `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason, CHECK IT. But since you get the undefined index warning, I'm going to go with no upload performed at all, or a typo in the field name (which IS case sensitive).

Comment: ...plus, if folder is writeable and that you've verified that all required elements have been included in the form. Insert **BIG QUESTION MARK** here:_

Comment: [**Read the *`(ever so fabulous)`* manual**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Check write permissions for nobody user. You can use chmod command to change directory permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my basic fixes to this script. They focus on using [`file_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) & [`is_dir`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.is-dir.php) before any other actions—like the [`move_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) process—are taken:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "crypto_new.php";
$target_path  = "./";
if (file_exists($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']) && is_dir($target_path)) {
  $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
    //stuff
  }
}
```

That said, this might stop the PHP notices & warnings, but the underlying issue will still exist. Meaning, no more error messages! But the file won’t me acted on.

The big thing for me here is what & where is the directory `./`? Does that exist in the context of the PHP script? Can Apache (which runs PHP) access `./` and write files there? Meaning, are the directory permissions for `./` usable by Apache?

In general, relative paths like this are a pain & cause of many avoidable headaches. So I would recommend you simply set that to a full path like this:

```
$target_path  = "/full/path/to/my/files/";
```

And then see if it works.

But this is really the best anyone can do with the small snippet of code you are providing. For all anyone knows, the rest of the form/upload process could be screwing up as well. And when it gets to this point, it’s just the last stage of failure in a broken process.

But I am fairly confident that the recommendation to set a full path for `$target_path` and checking file/directory permissions will clear this issue up.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful feedback. However, the answer to the problemed turned out to be as trivial as the fact that the partition the script resides on was full, and hence no space left to write files :P